# New to React: Using an async/await fetch request to return userData into a component

Tags: reactjs

New to React:I am using async/await to return user data to a component after login. However, my fetch call is firing prior to the login process. What am I doing incorrectly? Thank you in advance.

```
import React from 'react'
import { LoginButton } from '../FormElements/LoginButton';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import eglogo from '../../../assets/images/eglogo.png'
import genericUser from '../../../assets/images/generic-user.png'
import Link from 'next/link'

// ********************************************************
// ****** UserProfile Element Definitions
// ****** (styled-components) -- EricGuest
// ********************************************************

const ProfileContainer = styled.div`
    padding: 15px 0 25px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;`

const ProfileImageContainer = styled.div`
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background: #303e48;
    border: 3px solid #4d6373;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 7px;
    margin:0 10px 0 35px;
    float: left;`

const ProfileImage = styled.img`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 8%;
    background: #4d6373;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;`

const ProfileName = styled.h2`
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 13px 0 0 0;`

const LoginText = styled.h3`
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: .75em;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 00033px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    clear: left;`

const NameSpan = styled.span`
    margin-right: 10px;`

const ProfileEmail = styled.a`
    text-align: left;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    text-decoration: none;
    transition:.3s all ease-in-out;
    &:hover{
    color: #1d9add;
    text-decoration: none;
    }`

export const judgeSoul = () => {
    window.location.replace('http://localhost:8081/auth/google?returnURL=http://localhost:3000');
}

export class UserProfile extendsReact.Component < Props > {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            profile: []
        };
    };
    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8081/auth/me';
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include'
        });
        const userData = await response.json();
        this.setState({
            profile: userData,
            loading: false
        });
    };
    render = () => (
        <div>
            {this.state.loading || !this.state.profile ? (
                <ProfileContainer>
                    <ProfileImageContainer>
                        <ProfileImage src={genericUser} />
                    </ProfileImageContainer>
                    <LoginText>Please Log In</LoginText>
                    <LoginButton />
                </ProfileContainer>
            ) : (
                    <ProfileContainer>
                        <ProfileImageContainer>
                            <ProfileImage src={eglogo} />
                        </ProfileImageContainer>
                        <ProfileName>
                            <NameSpan>
                                {this.state.profile.firstName}
                            </NameSpan>
                            {this.state.profile.lastName}
                        </ProfileName>
                        <ProfileEmail href="/">
                            {this.state.profile.email}
                        </ProfileEmail>
                        <LoginButton />
                    </ProfileContainer>
                )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue with your condition.

just use

```
this.state.loading
```

instead of

```
this.state.loading || !this.state.profile
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, the loading state is conditional on whether the userData has been loaded. Removing " || !this.state.profile ?..." fails to compile:
Failed to compile
SyntaxError: /Users/eric.guest/repos/backoffice/components/global/offcanvas/UserProfile.tsx: Unexpected token, expected "}" (109:9)
 <LoginButton />
</ProfileContainer>
         ):(
          ^
<ProfileContainer>
<ProfileImageContainer>
<ProfileImage src={ eglogo } />
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.